# Child list unique key prop even when using a unique key in react

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error, `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` in a react app. I initially used `user.id` as the key but after some reading found out that react expects the key to be a string. I have now changed it to `user.username` but still getting the error.

I have printed the `user.username` value out to console to confirm that it is a string and are unique.

this is my code for mapping over object and displaying them

```
            {this.state.page.content.map((user) => (
              <div className="col-xl-4 col-m-12 mb-4">
              <UserListItem key={user.username} user={user} />
              {console.log(user.username)}
              </div>
            ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key needs to be at the *topmost* element returned - putting the key in a child element (where that child is the only child) won't achieve anything. You need:

```
{this.state.page.content.map((user) => (
  <div key={user.username} className="col-xl-4 col-m-12 mb-4">
    <UserListItem user={user} />
  </div>
))}
```